# Best way to use different viewCell layout

Tags: ios, iphone, ios10

I have been googling for this a while now, but didn't find a solution.

I am using a nib file which defines a view cell which I am reusing on multiple table views.

**My goal is it to have different view cell layout for different phone sizes.**
e.g.
- iPhone 6s need to show more information (labels, texts etc.)
- images should be positioned on the right (iphone 5), on the left for iphone 6

I think sizeClasses do not fit this problem right? Should I use complete different nib files for this?

Comment: Hi, ;) yeah of course I m not serious with that design it should just visualize my problem. I want to hide some labels on smaller screens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you should not use "complete different nib files". Use *one* nib file.

Each table view data source's `cellForRowAt:` will be called for every row of the cell before the cell is displayed. At that point, the cell has been loaded from the nib. If there are cell interface elements such as labels that you want to eliminate because you think the screen is too small (or because they don't apply to this particular table), that is the place to do it (by hiding or removing them).